# How can I catch the Killer Rabbit of Caerbannog?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Playing on the 1.8 snapshots, I came across a very rare rabbit known as the Killer Rabbit of Caerbannog. He looked a little bit like this:

[image]

If I make him a cage, how can I catch him and get him into it?

Comment: Do you have the holy hand grenade?

Comment: @slow_excellence Make sure you count to 3 before throwing.  Not 4, not 2 (unless continuing on to 3), and most certainly not 5.

Comment: I would seriously suggest removing that picture. It's not at all relevant to the question and it makes the post look like a joke. I know that it's a fun reference, but it really makes it look like you're not asking about something that's actually in the game.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Done

Comment: @murgatroid99 i thought that at first given the image and the comments before i read `1.8 snapshot` and remembered that Rabbits may be added in 1.8

Comment: Just to make sure this is clear, my comment was referring to the previous revision, which had a picture of Monty Python, not Minecraft.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Anyone that is interested can look through the revision history at the time of your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the other answers both work, I found it inconvenient to transport the rabbit to his cage after he was caught.

I ended up using a mine-cart to pick up my rabbit and transport him to his new home:

[image]

Leading my evil friend to his trap:

[image]

Got him!:

[image]

I then led tracks straight into his new home:

[image]

...and switched the tracks:

[image]

I finally closed off the cage where he sat quietly:

[image]

The Killer Rabbit of Caerbannog still is currently still in his cage, and I can roam about the world without worry. The killer rabbit is also worry free, as Holy Hand Grenades cannot breach his cell.

### EDIT:

Apparently forming a secret alliance with passing creepers, the killer rabbit was trying to escape. Luckily I had been forewarned of this uttermost danger and had the time to up the security near his cell:

[image]

Comment: You know, he's actually kinda cute in a minecart, just sitting there...

Comment: "That's the most foul, cruel, and bad-tempered rodent you ever set eyes on!"

Comment: It still looks cute in minecraft...

Comment: A single Creeper could blow that cage wide open.  

You laugh as though it would never happen.  I laugh secure in the knowledge that it will one day sneak up on you from behind, and unleash this deadly beast unto the unknowing world.

Comment: The creepers were planning an rabbit breakout behind my back! I knew it....

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rabbit#section_5), there is a 1 out of 1000 chance that this rabbit will appear when spawned from a spawn egg. If you want to summon it in creative you can try this command.

```
/summon Rabbit ~ ~ ~ {RabbitType:99}
```

Do he warned though, this rabbit is quite dangerous, as seen in the damage stats.

```
Easy: 5 damage
Normal: 8 damage
Hard: 12 damage
```

As for catching it, I don't believe that it is lured by carrots, so you might have to lure it in by letting it follow you, trying to kill you, then seal off the cage when it gets in.

If I've gotten any info wrong, or need to change something please do tell me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Killer Rabbit is hostile towards players so luring it around isn't tricky- it will try to move towards you and attack if it can. Just stand near enough that it can chase you (but keep enough distance that it doesn't hit you- it does more than twice the damage of a zombie).

Trapping it is not difficult. It doesn't have any special jumping abilities so an enclosure of fences or a 2 block deep pit should theoretically work.