# Is it possible to trap a Creeper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to trap a creeper so that i can transport it to a secure room in my base and then name it so it won't despawn.

Is it possible to trap a creeper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, although it can be very dangerous.

There are two ways I would do it:

### Method 1: RUN!

This method involves delicate manoeuvres and is more difficult than the second method. You will only need a couple of solid blocks to do this method.

1. Create a passageway to the room in your base.
2. Make sure the passage is high enough that once the creeper falls into the room, he cant get out.
3. Make a 2x1 doorway for you to escape though (you will need to close this off quickly).
4. Find a creeper and lead him through the passageway and into the room (make sure you have some blocks to block off the doorway first).
5. Once the creeper has been led into the room, run out of the doorway you made and quickly close it off behind you.

Your friendly neighbourhood creeper will be contained nicely in the room.

**Important:** Creepers will only chase you while you are within 16 blocks of them, and will only explode once within 1 block of you. You must keep the distance between you in between 2 and 16 blocks while being followed by the creeper.

Block distances from the "[Creeper](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper)" page on the wiki.

### Method 2: I like trains!

This method is fun to do, and slightly safer than the first method. You will need some rails, powered rails, and a couple of redstone torches.

1. Create a passageway to the room in your base
2. Build a small minecart loop and send a minecart around it.
3. Connect the loop to rails leading into the room.
4. Lead a creeper into the loop so he gets caught in the minecart.
5. Use a redstone torch to switch the track, leading the creeper into the room in your base.
6. Block off the passageway.

The creeper will be in the room, in the minecart.

The problem with this method is that it is almost impossible to retrieve the tracks from the room, as the creeper is patrolling around. It is safer than the first method however, because you don't need to get as close to the creeper.

**Note:** If you are confused about this method, have a look at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177126/how-can-i-catch-the-killer-rabbit-of-caerbannog/177267#177267), where the same concept is used to trap and transport an evil rabbit.

### Name Tag

After you have gotten the creeper in the room using either method, you should then be able to give him his name tag. Break a single hole in the wall of the room and give him his name tag through it, being ready to move backwards if he starts to hiss.

Comment: +1 because you like trains : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHkKJfcBXcw

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can trap the creeper by leading it carefully down a hall, into the room you want to lock it into. Just remember to keep 2-3 block distance from you and the creeper so it doesn't start to blow. Max distance is 16 blocks before it no longer follows you.

To rename it, make sure you make a 3 block thick wall between you and the creeper, then plug the tag on it. The 3 block thick wall is to prevent it from blowing up in your face. Your reach should be around 5 blocks.

Comment: You can rename hostile mobs...

Comment: "Even hostile mobs like the Wither or Ghast can be named." taken from minecraft wiki

Comment: I have corrected my answer based on the new feedback.